# Is there a closed form for the inverse of $y=x^{x^x}$?

Tags: inverse, tetration, lambert-w

It's pretty well known, and easy to derive, that $y=x^x$ has the inverse $y=\frac{\ln x}{W(\ln x)}$. I've had no luck trying to work out the inverse of any larger power towers, though. Is there any simple form of the inverse known?

Comment: Probably most people wouldn't consider expressions that involve the Lambert W function closed-form.

Comment: @Travis: Based on what they do not considerate as a closed form?

Comment: Short answer no. Long answer: Some very long algebraic arguments using W(x).

Comment: By wikipedia's definition; 
In mathematics, a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression that can be expressed using a finite number of symbols. These symbols include constants, variables, certain well-known operations (e.g., + − × ÷), and certain well-known functions (e.g., nth root, exponent, logarithm, trigonometric functions, and inverse hyperbolic functions). Lambert-W function isn't an elementary function so the answer is no.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $y=(x^x)^x$ is probably not equal to what the OP is asking.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583907/solution-to-eex-x-and-other-applications-of-iterated-functions

Comment: @Ali Caglayan LOL, you can express it using Lambert function? Please, make an answer!

Comment: @Travis LOL, you can express it using Lambert function? Please, make an answer!

Comment: @Anixx I doubt that it is possible to do so, at least not without invoking additional special functions.

Comment: I have discussed this a bit, but only got a power series, not a closed form. see http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/Wexzal_Superroot.pdf for the initial essay, then on my announcement in the "Tetrationforum" there came up a discussion 
http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1033   (superroot discussion) 
http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1033&pid=8137#pid8137 a concurring approach 
http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=1216 the paper (possibly not directly downloadable)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [*Other super roots*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Other_super-roots) at [*Tetration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

The closest possible solution comes from noting $x^{x^x}=$ $^3x$.$$^3x=y$$$$x=\sqrt[3]{y}_s$$Also known as the super-cube root.  Similar solution applies to higher towers.

Unlike $\sqrt{y}_s$, other super-roots are not definable in terms of known functions.